# Redis connection has been closed

Tags: redis, nestjs, nestjsbull

I ran into a problem regarding queues, or rather connecting to Redis. Created a queue for sending emails. I did a test run. Everything worked (not counting the error with the mail, but this is my jamb), but then nest refused to connect to Redis, issuing

```
        self.flushQueue(new Error(utils_1.CONNECTION_CLOSED_ERROR_MSG));
                        ^
Error: Connection is closed.
```

I tried to flush redis, and restart my open server, also tried restart my PC, but nothing happend